# cannot import name shared_memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I got a problem when trying shared memory access with python. I used multiprocessing library from Python Standard Library, but it's not worked when I try to import shared_memory module.

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
```

Result

```sh
ImportError: cannot import name shared_memory
```

I tried with Python 2 and Python 3, and all of them have the same problem.
Is there any suggestion about this problem?

Answer (score 17):

As of Python 3.7, `multiprocessing.shared_memory` is not yet actually a thing that exists. Wait for 3.8, then get 3.8. It will exist in 3.8.

Comment: What do you mean "is not a thing" ?

Comment: @zd5151: There is no such module on Python 3.7.